# How to Make Existing Database Records Unique Using UUIDs Without Disrupting Relations or Client Data?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I'm facing a database challenge where I need to ensure that each record in the database is unique for sharing data across multiple databases. However, some of our clients have large amounts of existing data, and I want to make this change without disrupting existing relations or client data. How can I achieve this?

I've considered the approach of adding a UUID column to each model and generating UUID values for existing records. Then, I would change the primary key to be the generated UUID. However, I'm uncertain about the potential consequences of this approach. Can anyone provide guidance on the best practices for implementing this change and ensuring data integrity?

for make my idea more clear :
i want to do somthing like this
`

```
    //
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // Add a new UUID column as the primary key.
        // Step 1: Create a new UUID column
        $table->uuid('uuid')->default(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::raw('UUID()'));

        // Step 2: Populate the UUID column with UUID values
        DB::table('users')->get()->each(function ($row) {
            DB::table('users')->where('id', $row->id)->update(['uuid' => Str::uuid()]);
        });

        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users DROP PRIMARY KEY');

        // Add the primary key constraint to 'uuid'
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (uuid)');

    });
```

`
this code is not working could i do somthing similar by anyway ?

Comment: Adding a new column cannot impact data integrity or relationships to other tables. You need to add the same column to other tables for this to be a problem.

Comment: when records have been generted it asscoitve with other ,how can now it will sould asscoitive with eachother ?

Comment: As with any other case: insert the uuidv value into another table. Althought I woukd consider adding the new uuid field as a unique field and leave the pk and fks intact

Comment: primary keys don't extend beyond a particular data base.  You don't need the UUID to be the primary key.  Just an additional identifier that is unique.